# CurrentTime to Day in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm try to make a helper funcion that give the date in Day format, so I have the following code

```
localDay :: Day
localDay = do 
  now <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime
  utctDay now
```

But get the following error

```
Couldn't match type ‘m0 b0’ with ‘Day’
Expected type: m0 UTCTime -> (UTCTime -> m0 b0) -> Day
  Actual type: m0 UTCTime -> (UTCTime -> m0 b0) -> m0 b0
In a stmt of a 'do' block: now <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime
In the expression:
  do { now <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime;
       utctDay now }
In an equation for ‘localDay’:
    localDay
      = do { now <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime;
             utctDay now }
```

Really I can't understant the reason of the error in this case because now should be of Type `UTCTimẹ`

Comment: why do you use `liftIO` in this case?

Comment: `liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a` is used to lift an IO action into another monad that is capable of doing IO;  it does not let you exit the `IO` monad altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCurrentTime :: IO UTCTime`, so you can't simply return a `Day` value; you can only return an `IO Day` value (ignoring `unsafePerformIO`)

```
localDay :: IO Day
localDay = fmap utctDay getCurrentTime
```